# How can I populate a field of a form calling a web server with a parameter in Orbeon?

Tags: web-services, dynamic, parameters, orbeon

I need to populate some fields depending on the selection of a dynamic dropdown.
Those fields need to use a WS to get the value using the selection as parameter.
I'm working with CE.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question is in the context of a form you've created with Form Builder:

- With Orbeon Forms PE, you can do this with the Form Builder UI by creating an [HTTP Service](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/http-services.html) corresponding to your Web Service, and creating an [action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/actions.html) that calls the service upon the value of your dynamic dropdown changing.
- With Orbeon Forms CE, you can't use the Form Builder UI, as services and actions are [only supported in the PE](http://www.orbeon.com/download), and would need to resort to writing your own XForms code that does this.

Comment: Can you tell me what components and functionality of CE should be used?  Is it necessary to write xforms code directly?

Comment: @Bruno You would need to write [XForms code](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_2.0) to call the service, and you can then populate the fields based on what the service returned. The first step is to use an `xf:submission` (see section 11 of the spec) to do the actual call, and save the result in a local instance.